# Help with Compact array-operations in Matlab to replace for-loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop

I need to simulate a forest fire and for this, I need a colormap.
The colormap has 51 rows, which looks like this:

First 10 is a gradient from dark green to yellow and the rows are generated by:

```
uint8color = [4 112 31];
for i = -1:8
    cmap = double(uint8(uint8color + i*[30 27 3])) / 255
end;
```

Next is a single blue line:

```
cmap(11, :) = [0 0.5 0.9];
```

And the remaining 40 lines go from yellow over red to almost black, done by the following:

```
for i=19:-1:-20
    farve = double(uint8(uint8farve + i*[12 12 5])) / 255;
end;
```

This works fine, however, I would like to avoid using loops wherever possible and try to use the compact array-operations Matlab is capable of

I'm quite stuck with the above though, not realising how (and if) I can use the compact notation, but still have the index at hand.

For the first 10 rows, something like:

```
cmap(1:10, :)
```

Would substitute the for-loop, but it would require me to somehow still extract an index and subtract 2 from the value (1:10 -> -1:8)

I hope there's a Matlab guru somewhere, who can point me in the right direction

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop can be rewritten as:

```
uint8color = [4 112 31];
i = (-1:8)';
cmap = double(uint8(repmat(uint8color, length(i), 1) + i*[30 27 3])) / 255;
```

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with all those casts, though...

Comment: This works perfectly! I can't believe the answer was that simple, thank you very much.
In regards to the casts, I know it looks weird, but without them the values are messed up